# TemplatedControl Expander header not showing

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have created a TemplatedControl as follows,

```
namespace Presentation.Common.Controls
{
public sealed class ExpanderEx : Expander
{
 public ExpanderEx()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ExpanderEx);
        }
}
}
```

In the ResourceDictionary inside xaml, I have a style as follows, (this same style when applied on a normal Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Expander works just fine. I can see the header)

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Presentation.Common.Controls">
  <Style TargetType="local:ExpanderEx">
        <Setter Property="HeaderStyle" Value="{StaticResource LightExpanderHeaderToggleButtonStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    </Style>

<Style x:Key="LightExpanderHeaderToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource FontSizeMedium}" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" 
                                  Background="{StaticResource BrushBeckmanAquaA1}">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush" Color="Transparent"></SolidColorBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" Opacity="0.2"></SolidColorBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" Opacity="0.3"></SolidColorBrush>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle x:Name="HoverPanel" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="Transparent" />

                        <Slider x:Name="ArrowRotation" Maximum="180" Minimum="-180" Visibility="Collapsed" Value="90" />

                        <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" Margin="12" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="12" Glyph="&#xE76C;" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
                                          Foreground="White">
                            <FontIcon.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform />
                            </FontIcon.RenderTransform>
                        </FontIcon>

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                                  HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                                  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                                  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                  ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                                  Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                         To="0.0"
                                                         Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundListLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                         To="0.0"
                                                         Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                              Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundListMediumBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                         To="0.0"
                                                         Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                         To="0.0"
                                                         Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                         To="{Binding ElementName=ArrowRotation, Path=Value}"
                                                         Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                         To="{Binding ElementName=ArrowRotation, Path=Value}"
                                                         Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                              Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                         To="{Binding ElementName=ArrowRotation, Path=Value}"
                                                         Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                         To="{Binding ElementName=ArrowRotation, Path=Value}"
                                                         Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminateDisabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HoverPanel"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandDirectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="RightDirection" />

                                <VisualState x:Name="DownDirection" />

                                <VisualState x:Name="LeftDirection">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ArrowRotation.Value" Value="-90" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="UpDirection">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ArrowRotation.Value" Value="-90" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now I am using this Templated control inside a new user control as follows,

```
<controls:ExpanderEx x:Name="ExpanderLisSharedSettings" Grid.Row="0" Header="Hello">

</control:ExpanderEx>
```

Problem is it never shows the Expander header. So I tried changing the background property to green where it says   and it never seems to change the background color. Please help. I am using the Microsoft Controls Toolkit Expander Control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the control doesn't show is that you haven't defined an `ExpanderEx` template.

Generally TemplateControl has Template structure, such as this:

```xml
<!-- other style code -->
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ExpanderEx">
            <!-- template code -->
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Although your `ExpanderEx` inherits `Expander`, it does not inherit its template style, and you also set `this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ExpanderEx);`, UWP finds the style of `ExpanderEx`, but it cannot be displayed because you have not defined.

So if you want to display, you may copy `Expander`'s default template style to the new `ExpanderEx` and modify it.